# Curl of an inner product with a curl: $\nabla \times \left<A|\nabla A\right>$

Tags: physics, vector-analysis

This seems extremely trivial, but I'd like some clarification on why the following statement is true:
\begin{equation}
\nabla \times \left<A|\nabla A\right> = \left<\nabla A\right|\times\left|\nabla A\right>.
\end{equation}
I tried interpreting the braket as an inner product, but the outer product of an inner product (i.e. an outer product of vector and a scalar) yields no meaningful answer. Thanks!

Comment: Where did this show up as I don't know if I've ever seen this in any QM text

Comment: @Triatticus It's in Berry's original paper on the Berry Phase: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2397741?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents on page 3 (47 in the journal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guessing, but perhaps this is the idea:

$\nabla \times \left<A|\nabla A\right>$

$ = \nabla \times \int A^* \nabla A$

$ = \int \nabla \times (A^* \nabla A)$

$ = \int (\nabla A^*) \times (\nabla A)$

$ = \left<\nabla A\right|\times\left|\nabla A\right>$

Comment: Why does line 3 --> 4 hold? That's the step I didn't get..

Comment: I'm aware of those rules but I still don't see it... $A^*$ isn't a scalar, neither is $\nabla A$ afaik? I feel kinda dumb ... :(

Comment: $A$ (and hence $A^*$) is a scalar and $\nabla A$ is a vector. Where is the issue?

Comment: Ah okay, I get it now. I would've suggested $\nabla \times (a \vec b) = -(\vec b \times \nabla a) + a(\nabla \times \vec b)$, taking $a = A^*$ and $\vec b = \nabla A$ instead, but this works for me now. The confusion arose from the tensor-rank of $A$. Thanks!

Comment: Ah I meant curl only, my bad :( Will remove the faulty comment now